# Dropdown Item Width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Well Hello.

Please help me out if anyone can.

I am creating a dropdown in React with the help of Bootstrap. I did everything but the dropdown items doesn't take up the full width. Even when i set it to 100%, it doesn't take up and also the shadow appears on it which I can't seem to remove it. I am a beginner and still learning so please forgive me if this is not a good question lol.

This screenshot is after i set the width to 100%.

100% Width:

[image]

And this is a screenshot when i set the width to 0%. It removes the shadow but the item doesn't take full area.

0% Width:

[image]

And Here is my code. I am using Bootstrap in React.

Main Component:

[image]

CSS:

[image]

As i said, I am learning so i dont know whats the correct way to solve this.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Posting screenshots of html is not helpful. Posting the actual html code would be great.

Comment: ok sorry. I dont ask questions here frequently. I will format the code in the best way and paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
text-align: justify;
display: inline-block;
```